# Minkowski functional of an open set and its boundary

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is this:

Let $(X , \left \| . \right \|)$ a $\mathbb{R}-$Normed space; $0\in C\subseteq X$ open and convex;         $p$ the Minkowski functional in $C$,   $x\in X$.

if $p(x)>0$ then $\frac{x}{p(x)}\in \partial C$

DEMONSTRATION:

Recall that:     $\begin{matrix}
p: &X&\rightarrow &\mathbb{R}& \\ 
 & x&\mapsto &inf&\left \{ \alpha >0/\frac{x}{\alpha }\in C \right \}\ 
\end{matrix}$

So far I have this:

1. to not write so much I have already demonstrated this: $\forall \alpha > p(x) : \frac{x}{\alpha}\in C$ and $\forall \alpha \leq  p(x) : \frac{x}{\alpha}\notin C$
2. Taking $x\in C$ and r>0, and defining $\beta := \frac{2p(x)\left \| x \right \|}{p(x)r + 2\left \| x \right \|}$ then it is quickly shown that $\beta<p(x)$ and $\frac{x}{\beta } \in B(\frac{x}{p(x)},r)$ then we would have to  $B(\frac{x}{p(x)},r)\bigcap C^{c}\neq \emptyset$

HELP:

The help I am asking for is that you guide me to find $\beta >p(x)$ such that $\frac{x}{\beta } \in B(\frac{x}{p(x)},r) , C$

I have tried to generate this beta but I have not been able to, or how would you do it, I welcome suggestions and thank you for them.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of $p(x)$,  There  exists $\alpha_n \to p(x)$ such that $\frac  x{\alpha_n} \in C$. Since $\frac x {p(x)} =\lim \frac  x{\alpha_n} $ it follows that $\frac x {p(x)} \in \overline C$. If $\frac x {p(x)} \notin \partial C$ the $\frac x {p(x)} \in C$.  But $C$ is open so $\frac  x r \in C$ for some $r <p(x)$ [See below]. This contradicts the definition of $p(x)$.

[Suppose $B(\frac x {p(x)},\delta) \subseteq C$. Then $\|\frac  x  r-\frac  x {p(x)}\|<\delta$ provided $|r-p(x)|<s$ with $0 <s<\frac {\delta \|x\|p(x)^{2}} 2$ and $0<s<\frac {p(x)} 2$. To show this you need to observe that $r >\frac {p(x)} 2$ in this case].